Spring Boot DynamoDB Dependency Issue
I have created a table in my DynamoDB account; however, I can't seem to get this dependency issue straight in my pom.xml file.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>recommender.recommenderBackend</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>backend</name>
    <description>Recommender Backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>22</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.26.5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I've looked at a number of documentation sources and I am trying to resolve this using ChatGPT, but to no avail. Basically, I have tried to include the dynamodb dependency within both the dependencyManagement tags and the dependencies tags, but neither seem to work. Currently, I am getting the error "Dependency 'software.amazon.awssdk:dynamodb:' not found ". When I try to import the DynamoDbClient in my Controller class, it obviously isn't working. Can someone point me in the right direction?

It works for me. Can you share a complete pom.xml rather than just a snippet? Also, are you accessing Maven Central or on a network where it's proxied or mirrored?

Hi I just edited it to include the full snippet, can you take another look at it? Thank you.

That pom.xml works for me too. Can you share the complete output from Maven when you try to build the project?

There is an example of using DyanmoDB within a Spring Boot project in the AWS Code Example Github.
Creating a Spring Boot application that queries Amazon DynamoDB data
Just tested this project and it works fine....

